# Finding maximal ideals that contract to $(y-b)$ in $K[y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the ring $$R=\frac{K[X,Y]}{(X^2-(Y^2+Y^3))K[X,Y]}$$  and let $x,y$ be the equivalence classes of $X,Y$.
The extension $K[y]\subseteq R$  is integral, therefore if we take any maximal ideal in $K[y]$ of the form $(y-b)K[y]$ with $b\in K$, there exists a finite number of maximal ideals in $R$ that contract to $(y-b)K[y]$ in $K[y]$.

Surely  $Ax+A(y-b)$ must be one of those ideals, as contracting in $K[y]$ kills $Ax$.

I'm having some trouble figuring out if there are some other maximals that contract to $(y-b)K[y]$ .